# REST: openapi generation - response needs XML/JSON conversion while request is XML String

Tags: xml, rest, jackson, openapi-generator, spring-resttemplate

I'm building a client for an API where endpoint accepts XML for request (application/xml) and provides XML/JSON back in response (applicaiton/json, application/xml)

At the moment of calling the API I already have the XML string to submit in the bode of the HTTP request -> I'd like to avoid any marshallings/conversion to transform string to DTO before the API call, however for the response I'd like transformation to XML/JSON to happen so that I could inspect some of required fields.

My problem is that the openapi generated client expects to get DTO on input of the post service call. I'm using maven plugin to generate openapi sources and struggling to find configuration which would help to generate classes who will accept String (with XML) as input and return DTO for post methods.

Appreciate any hint.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I did updated signature of the method manually to receive string instead of a DTO.

That also works.